# Visual Studio Work Item Editor Interface Corruption

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

Has anyone ever seen behavior like this in the Visual Studio 2010 Work Item editor, and found a solution:

[image: Work Item Editor]

The odd outlining of the upper controls is not a big deal, but the lower sections consist of several tabs that are completely invisible. They exist, and can be tabbed through, but you simply cannot see them.

This issue seems to crop up randomly. Sometimes I will open a work item and it will render like this, sometimes it will render correctly. Sometimes simply closing and reopening the work item will correct the issue, sometimes it won't.

Comment: Yes I see this too but haven't found a solution yet.  Running Visual Studio 2010 SP1 on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 SP1 and TFS 2010 SP1.  I'm running on an ASUSTeK CG5275 with v0502, 7/16/2010 bios version and v8.15.10.2993 drivers for the Intel HD Graphics video controller. I have two monitors connected at different resolutions.  Do you have any similarity in my hardware?  I also have several Visual Studio extensions installed and we are using custom work item templates.